# Create slideshow with photos from photoalbum on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiimage

I want to create a little Slideshow App for iPad with images from iPads photoalbum. Is there a way to get all photos of photoalbum in an array or dictionary?
Does someone has samplecode?

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Even if it's possible, Apple will very likely reject your app for duplication of built-in functionality (Photos.app).

Comment: Don't think so because my App. will have a lot of other interessting features. Please help if you can! Thanks